# memory device: reason for bad blocks and how to fix it

Tags: ssd, badblocks

I have a 64G micro SSD that is corrupted.

I had put it into a device that can handle only 32G.

Question: can this damage the SSD, and if so, how would that happen?

I have run the badblocks command, and it starts counting 1, 2, 3, ... .

I have seen https://searchstorage.techtarget.com/definition/bad-block and it tells me that a "bad block" is either really a hardware fail or a "soft" error when some sanity check (as CRC) fails. I guess, in the later case it could be repaired by blanking out all of the device with dd, but that would take ages.

Comment: CRC errors are a sign of a problem; ie. you may have a storage-bit than can store a 0, but not a 1 - so if a 0 is there no CRC errors are detected (thus a re-format may 'clear' the CRC error) but if you store data that requires a 1 to be stored there - it can't store and thus is converted to a 0 (thus corruption!).  Ignoring CRC errors by re-format can lead to data corruption & isn't usually wise in my experience.

Comment: @guiverc I don't really know if it is a CRC error, some other soft error where only the memory is inconsistent, or if the device (or block) is hardware damaged beyond repair. Is the CRC, or equivalent, stored in the same block?

Comment: CRCs are usually for a sector; a block/cluster/inode is usually a number of sectors - but this is fs (*file-system*) specific

Comment: @guiverc I was not asking for what thingy the control information is stored but where. If in the same thingy, then it is cleared with the same thingy. If it is stored in a different thingy, dd only provokes the mismatch. Big difference.

Comment: You **don't** bad block a SSD!